# Prevent Duplication of mail id & ph num in Firebase Application without authentication after submitting form & retrieving the data using Snapshot

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to prevent duplication of email id and phone number, so first after submitting the form I'm checking for the email id and phone number in database. If any one of them exists it should display error message `email already exists in the database` or else it should push the data to firebase realtime database. My application is working fine for first submit of the form. If I'm submitting the form with new values for the second time the data is getting added twice. If I submit the form with the new values 3rd time, the values are getting submitted 3 times and getting pushed into my firebase database and even it's throwing the error message. It gets into both if and else condition from second submission of the form with new values. Any fixes, please help me.

Below is my code which I have tried

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// Listen for form submit 
document.getElementById('contactform1').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);
// Submit form 
function submitForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Get values 
  var fname = getInputVal('fname');
  var lname = getInputVal('lname');
  var newEmail = getInputVal('email');
  var newPhone = getInputVal('phone');
  var newskills = getInputVal('skills');
  var newjobId = getInputVal('jid');
  var newlinkedin = getInputVal('linkedin');
  var newgithub = getInputVal('github');
  var newlocation = getInputVal('location');

  saveMessage(fname, lname, newEmail, newskills, newPhone, newjobId, newlinkedin, newgithub, newlocation);
}

function saveMessage(fname, lname, newEmail, skills, newPhone, jobId, linkedin, github, location) {
  let ref = firebase.database().ref().child('self/data/');
  ref.once('value', snap => {
    if (snap.exists()) {
      snap.forEach(childSnapshot => {
        var email = childSnapshot.child('email').val();
        var phone = childSnapshot.child('phone').val();
        console.log(status);
        if (newEmail.trim() === email.trim() || newPhone.trim() === phone.trim()) { //check if email exists 
          console.log("email already exists in the database");
        } else {
          console.log('hello');
          firebase.database().ref().child('self/data/').push().set({
            name: fname + " " + lname,
            email: email,
            phone: phone,
            skills: skills,
            jobId: jobId,
            linkedin: linkedin,
            github: github,
            location: location
          });
        }
      });
    } else {
      firebase.database().ref().child('self/data/').push().set({
        name: fname + " " + lname,
        email: email,
        phone: phone,
        skills: skills,
        jobId: jobId,
        linkedin: linkedin,
        github: github,
        location: location
      });
    }
  });
}

// Function to get get form values 
function getInputVal(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id).value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah it seems like there is a logic issue inside the loop try that way:

```
 function saveMessage(fname, lname, newEmail, skills, newPhone, jobId, linkedin, github, location) {
    let ref = firebase.database().ref().child('self/data/');
    ref.once('value', snap => {
      let isDuplicated = false;
    if (snap.exists()) {
      snap.forEach(childSnapshot => {
        var email = childSnapshot.child('email').val();
        var phone = childSnapshot.child('phone').val();
        console.log(status);
        if (newEmail.trim() === email.trim() || newPhone.trim() === phone.trim()) { //check if email exists 
          isDuplicated = true;
        } 
      });
    }
    if (snap.exists() && !isDuplicated) {
      firebase.database().ref().child('self/data/').push().set({
        name: fname + " " + lname,
        email: email,
        phone: phone,
        skills: skills,
        jobId: jobId,
        linkedin: linkedin,
        github: github,
        location: location
      });
    }
    });
    }
```